# Does a UK refugee passport holder need a visa to enter France?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, refugees

I have a UK Refugee passport. Do I need a visa to go to France?

I want to go for two days with my husband, but I'm not quite sure if I can go without a visa.

Comment: The information that I have is that you need the refugee travel document _and_ a "titre de séjour qui lui permet de résider au Royaume-Uni" (residence permit to reside in the United Kingdom) in order to be visa exempt for France. I am trying to confirm this now...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a Travel Document (Convention of 28 July 1951), according to [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/) you do need a visa:

> Visa required.
>
> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Passengers with an Alien's passport issued by Estonia or Latvia for a
>   maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The max. stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their
>   stay and documents required for their next destination. Important:
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

unless you have a residence permit:

> Visa required.
>
> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Passengers with a with a Travel Document (Convention of 28 July 1951)
>   issued to refugees and a residence permit issued by Andorra, Monaco,
>   Switzerland or EEA Member State , for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The max. stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their
>   stay and documents required for their next destination.